# Is there any way that node_modules folder do not expand unecessarily when cmd+click on code in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, node-modules

When i do cmd+click on something in the code the node_modules folder gets expanded and in order to close it need to go all the way back to the top of that folder which is very annoying.Is there an way to avoid this?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

What I usually do is hiding the node_modules from my sidebar..

Go to: `File > Preferences > Settings`

Search for `files:exclude`

And fill up the `Exclude pattern` with `node_modules/` and hit **OK**

This way, I don't need to turn off the **auto reveal** functionality

Answer (score 2):

There is a way in vscode v1.74 to exclude specific files and folders from auto-revealing.  The new setting is

```
Explorer: Auto Reveal Exclude
```

from [Auto Reveal Exclude: Release Notes](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_74.md#allow-customization-of-explorer-autoreveal-logic-via-explorerautorevealexclude)

> ##### Allow customization of Explorer autoreveal logic via `explorer.autoRevealExclude`
>
> The highly upvoted issue Allow to set `explorer.autoReveal` per
> specific folder has been closed with the introduction of a new setting
> `explorer.autoRevealExclude`. This allows for configuring which files
> get autorevealed in the explorer if the autorevealing is enabled. The
> setting follows the same pattern as `files.exclude` by also supporting
> sibling matching via when clauses.

In fact, `node_modules` is excluded by default.

Comment: Recently I found that VSCode behaved differently than before, it turned out to be because of the new default option, thanks, I ended the dilemma of grabbing my hair with both hands.

Answer (score 1):

In settings, look  for **Explorer: Auto Reveal**

*Controls whether the explorer should automatically reveal and select files when opening them.*

You currently have it set `true`, which is the default value. Change the value to `false`.

Bring up settings with Control-, (comma) and then type `reveal ex` into the filter.

To scroll to the file that you are editing in the list of files, right-click on the file's tab, then select **Reveal in side bar**.

I wrote up [more information on my blog](https://www.mslinn.com/blog/2021/03/22/vscode-notes.html#reveal).

Comment: I corrected my answer. `focusNoScroll` still opens the folders. `false` does what you want.